# How to convert Kindle format (.mobi or .azw) with annotations to PDF?

Tags: kindle, pdf, conversion, annotations

I'm looking for a way to convert a Kindle book, with several annotations in it, to PDF format, so that my annotations are also saved in the PDF file.

Converting from .mobi or .azw to PDF seems pretty easy with Calibre, but is it possible to retain the annotations as well?

*EDIT*: How can I find Kindle locations in a PDF with the same text of the Kindle file? That is, how many characters or words are one location number? If this can be answered, I might be able to write a script to pass the annotations to the PDF file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. http://the-digital-reader.com/2015/02/21/how-to-download-your-kindle-notes-and-highlights-and-export-them/

My guess is that because PDF is ultimately a fixed layout format, the annotations from Kindle won't mean anything in PDF because they would need to be placed in certain positions on the PDF. But ebook formats aren't really about positions but flexible reflowable text.

If it's possible to convert to PDF, it might be possible to build a calibre plugin to position the annotations as well... But someone would have to do it...

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, I think I have to rephrase the question to: "how can I find Kindle locations in a PDF with the same text? That is, how many characters or words are one location number?" This link http://booksprung.com/how-long-is-a-location-in-a-kindle-ebook says it's supposed to be 150 chars + html tags. This makes it impossible to predict with certainty, and from some tests I ran it seems to be a bad predictor. Maybe it's not possible after all, even though it should be simple

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely try Installing Caliber on your desktop. It has options to convert ebooks from one format to another with ease . Your requirement will be efficiently handled by Caliber.

Comment: I already have Calibre:) It's a great software, but it cannot do what I asked (at least, I haven't found out how searching the internet)